# EXTJS How to swap the order of two childNodes?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am a newbie in EXTJS.
I am currently stuck on swapping the order of two tree nodes.

I tried to use

```
var temp = x.childNodes[index-1];
x.childNodes[index-1] = x.childNodes[index];
x.childNodes[index] = temp;
```

But on the tree panel, it shows that now the childNodes[index-1] is gone instead of swapping the order. I use fireBug to debug, and it seems like these two childNodes have swapped the order under their parentNode.
It is just not showing that on the tree panel.

What should I do? Refresh the tree panel or something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
var temp = x.childNodes[index-1].cloneNode(true);
x.childNodes[index-1] = x.childNodes[index];
x.childNodes[index] = temp;
```